# Nativescript Listview showing nothing

Tags: angular-ui-router, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a minimalist Nativescript hello world application. It has just 2 screens, 'Login' and 'List'.

Here is the flow:

1. User presses the login button in first screen.
2. Second screen is shown, which is suppose to show the list of names; but which shows nothing.
3. If I type even a single character in text field, it shows the list.

I have been scouring over Stack Overflow and Github, it seems the problem others are facing is a bit complicated, like "list not getting updated after http call" etc.

So it seems I am making some obvious mistake here, because this basic scenario should 'just work'. But that small mistake alludes me.

[image: Problem]

Here is my login file:

```
/*login.component.ts*/
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
import * as Rx from "rxjs";
import { MyFireLoginService } from '../../mobile-fire/fire-login.service'
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
  selector: "login",
  templateUrl: './pages/login/login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pages/login/login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {
  email: string = 'user1@site.com';
  password: string = 'password';
  user: Observable<any>;
  constructor(private fl: MyFireLoginService, private router: Router) {
    this.email = 'user1@site.com';
    this.password = 'password';
    this.user = fl.authState;
    this.watchUser();
  }
  watchUser(): void {
    this.user.subscribe((usr) => {
      if (usr.uid) {
        this.router.navigate(["/list"]);
      }
    })
  }
  login(): void {
    this.fl.loginWithEmail(this.email, this.password)
  }

}
```

and list file:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import firebase = require("nativescript-plugin-firebase");
import * as Rx from "rxjs";
import { MyFireLoginService } from '../../mobile-fire/fire-login.service'
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
  selector: "list",
  templateUrl: './pages/list/list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pages/list/list.component.css']
})
export class ListComponent {
  items: any[] = [];
  user: Observable<any>;

  constructor(private fl: MyFireLoginService,
    private router: Router) {
    this.user = fl.authState;
    this.watchUser();
    this.items = [{
      name: 'aks1'
    }, {
      name: 'aks2'
    }, {
      name: 'aks3'
    }]
  }

  watchUser(): void {
    this.user.subscribe((usr) => {
      if (!usr.uid) {
        this.router.navigate(["/"]);
      }
    })
  }
  private textChanged(e: any): void {
    console.log(e.value);
    // console.dir(this.items);
  }
  logout() {
    this.fl.logout()
  }
}
```

*list.component.html*

```
<ActionBar title="List" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <Button class="submit-button" text="Logout" (tap)="logout()"></Button>

    <TextField hint="empty field for testing.." (textChange)="textChanged($event)"></TextField>
    <Label *ngFor="let item of items" [text]="item.name"></Label>

    <!-- <GridLayout>
        <ListView id="list-of-items" [items]="items" class="small-spacing">
        <ng-template let-item="item">
            <Label [text]="item.name" class="medium-spacing"></Label>
        </ng-template>
        </ListView>
    </GridLayout> -->

</StackLayout>
```

*login.component.html*

```
<ActionBar title="Login" class="action-bar"></ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <Button class="submit-button" text="Sign in" (tap)="login()"></Button>
    <Label text="Hello world"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

EDIT: Here are the log for the life-cycle events of two components:

```
JS: LOGIN:ngDoCheck called
JS: LOGIN:ngAfterContentChecked called
JS: LOGIN:ngAfterViewChecked called
JS: Auth state changed.
JS: a <==== This is me typing 'a' in the textbox of LIST component
JS: LOGIN:ngDoCheck called
JS: LOGIN:ngAfterContentChecked called
JS: LOGIN:ngAfterViewChecked called
JS: LIST:ngOnInit called
JS: LIST:ngDoCheck called
JS: LIST:ngAfterContentInit called
JS: LIST:ngAfterContentChecked called
JS: LIST:ngAfterViewChecked called
```

What I find strange is that List component's init is not called until I type 'a' in the textbox inside List component. Also, LOGIN component's life-cycle events are called even after is it gone out of view.

**Update1**: I followed the tutorial on [nativescript.org](http://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-4#43-listview). The code there seems to be working fine. I suspect, there is something wrong with inclusion of firebase plugin. Will update when I know more.

**Update2**: I stubbed parts of firebase api I am using, it worked fine with dummy APIs.

Comment: Put content of `list.component.html` it can help too

Comment: Added both list.component.html and login.component.html.

Comment: I even tried without 'Listview', with simple 'label', all to no avail.

Comment: I think the items array should be an observable-array instead. Not sure about its rxjs representation, but that's imported as `import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array";` using the cross-platform modules observable

Comment: @pkanev, I tried with observable in conjunction with async pipe. Still not working!

Comment: can you not use ng-template and use template tag only?

Comment: @Dlucidone
I tried with "Label" tag, it is still not working.

Comment: i'm saying template inside listview? not label tag

Comment: Yes @Dlucidone, I got what you are saying. What I did is got rid of whole ListView and included ng-template tag. Then replaced that with :

    <Label *ngFor="let item of items" [text]="item.name"></Label>

Still no change.

Comment: I also tried with Listview  + template tag combo, It didn't worked either.

Comment: @zioninc, did you find a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue.

Comment: @TYMG, I am forcing change detection:
`keys: any[] = [];`
then 
`$keys.subscribe(res => { this.ngZone.run(() => { this.keys = res; }) }) `